# AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms' when creating new app

Tags: heroku, pyopenssl

I have been trying to create an app that should run through psiturk (I will eventuall post the app to MTurk). I am pretty sure I did everything here:

[https://psiturk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/heroku.html#:~:text=Heroku%20is%20a%20cloud%20service,autorun%20the%20code%20for%20you](https://psiturk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/heroku.html#:%7E:text=Heroku%20is%20a%20cloud%20service,autorun%20the%20code%20for%20you).

But, I am getting
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms'

I actually did all of these earlier, and I have an app that actually runs. I just want to create a new one. I copied everything from the old app, and created a new heroku app and .git for the new app. I don't understand how I can get this error with the new app while the old app is up and running.

I spent a lot of time on this issue... Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who encounters a similar issue, I found out that when I add

```
cryptography==38.0.4
```

to the `requirements.txt` file, the problem is resolved.